# How to authenticate static routes in FastAPI

Tags: fastapi, starlette

I am statically serving a folder via FastAPI following the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
```

How can I add basic authentication (user, password) to this route `/static`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulled directly from the FastAPI docs:  https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/

```py
import secrets

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials

app = FastAPI()

security = HTTPBasic()


def get_current_username(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    correct_username = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.username, "stanleyjobson")
    correct_password = secrets.compare_digest(credentials.password, "swordfish")
    if not (correct_username and correct_password):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect email or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )
    return credentials.username


@app.get("/users/me")
def read_current_user(username: str = Depends(get_current_username)):
    return {"username": username}
```

Comment: The part I still had to figure out is how to serve my static files without using the `StaticFiles` class. I ended up using the Template functionality provided by fastapi to serve a website: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question

Comment: This doesn't provide a solution to the question. Here there is a workaround https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/858#issuecomment-876564020

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure you can add basic authentication  to the route itself I add it directly to the endpoint. But here's a link with the best auth modules for fastapi. Hope it helps. I like FastAPI Login.

[FastAPI Auth](https://awesomeopensource.com/project/mjhea0/awesome-fastapi#auth)